# log rank p value interpretation from gepia 2

Tags: rna-seq, figure-explanation

How do i interpret the overall survival when the p value reported is not significant going by the standard convention .

Not sure what kind of test it runs while comparing the expression may be one non-parametric test , but the survival is kaplan meier on cox ph model which they have mentioned .

So is it a significant one if i have to tell in context of survival ?

[image: log rank]

Comment: Could you provide a bit of context? From which article did you get this? Why do you think it needs different interpretation when the p-value is above your threshold?

Comment: it's from gepia site so im looking for genes in databases which are significant across patient sample ,boxplot shows significant but the survival is not significant if i understand ,why is it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plot on the left shows that the gene has very different expression between two groups. However, according to the graph on the right, these high expression is not directly related to survival because both groups have similar survival time.
The gene expression so high might be to compensate for other deficiencies or problems.

Comment: yes both of them have similar survival  which is reflected in the log rank value ? in other words if i see the log rank value is not significant ,then i shouldn't consider it..

Comment: @krushnach You shouldn't consider it for what? Please [edit] the question to include more details (I don't even know which gene is: LAML or zbtb16??), perhaps a link to the result on the website is possible

Comment: okay i will do it. i cannot link it as it the result is stored and rendered there but here is the link http://gepia2.cancer-pku.cn/#survival the data set im using LAML gene is ZBTB16 you can have a look..

Comment: Ok, that's for the survival curve and the other plot were does it come from?

Comment: http://gepia2.cancer-pku.cn/#analysis this one

Comment: Ok, know I know how did you get these plots. But why do you need them ? Why are you looking at these plots? What are you looking for

Comment: as they were getting differentially expressed in leukemic stem cells and blast cells so was looking in TGCA how the survival is affected ..